# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on seconds convert to hrs/mins function

Tags: ios, swift, exception

I got the error message:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

In code, I was trying to convert the second counter started from 0 and to convert to hours and minutes. I really don't know what the  problem is.

```
let secondsQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.secondUnit(), doubleValue: seconds)
var str_1 = secondsQuantity.description
let range1 = str_1.rangeOfString("s")
str_1.removeRange(range1!)
h = Int(str_1)! / 3600
m = (Int(str_1)!  % 3600) / 60
s = Int(str_1)! % 60
let hour = "\(h) Hours, "
let min = "\(m) Minutes, "
let sec = "\(s) Seconds"
let sentance = "Time: " + hour + min + sec
timeLabel.text = sentence
```

Comment: Is range1 nil perhaps?

Comment: You force unwrap an optional with `!`, so it crashes when the value is nil. This is working as expected.

Comment: Learn how to debug a crash by visiting http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: I found Int(str_1) always getting the value nil, but there is a number string in str_1. Why Int(str_1) got nil?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. There is a nil and with your help, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether range1 is nil before using it. 
On top of that, I recommend you to try doing:

```
if let strIng = Int(str_q)
```

before you go ahead and do h = Int(str_1)! / 3600

Comment: After checking the value of the variable, there is a nil. Now it fixed. thank you.